# django-authopenid provider icons / buttons missing

Tags: django, openid, django-authopenid

I followed the setup instructions for django authopenid application.  As far as I can tell it is working properly.  However, I cannot see the provider buttons/icons for yahoo, google, etc on the sign in with openID portion.  Anyone had this problem?  Thanks.

Comment: as in the screen shot here under Test It http://www.grenadepod.com/2009/11/22/using-openid-for-authentication-in-django/

Answer (score 0):

If you are bothered *only* about getting the images and don't mind looking elsewhere, you can get the buttons from this open source project: [openid-selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/). See [this page](http://openid-selector.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo.html) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

turns out my issue had to do with media settings in settings.py.  I was plugging 'authopenid' into an existing project.  So, I already had settings related to media.  To solve it, I just the melded my media structure into the one in the 'authopenid' example that comes in the package.